# how I can to reply to message with my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to reply to message in discord with my bot but I can't understand how.
I watched some answers but i dosent get the answer. someone said I need to write this code:
`await message.reply('Hello!', mention_author=True)`

but it dosent work, I got an error:
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'reply'`

pls help me!

Comment: Discord.py changes their API every two weeks. The tutorial you looked at is probably outdated. I think you have to take a `context` argument in all of your commands now, and that first argument is probably missing. If your command is called `def example(msg)` right now, try calling it `def example(ctx, msg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example from the official discord.py github
https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/reply.py